# Некорректное отображение box-shadow для элементов в таблице в хроме

Tags: css, google-chrome

Возникла проблема при реализации теней для ячеек таблицы. Используя `box-shadow`, я задаю необходимые параметры тени, при этом в firefox тень отображается корректно, а вот в хроме и других браузерах на этом движке, с тенями проблемы, они отображаются некорректно. Есть ли какое решение для корректного отображения теней для ячеек таблицы в хроме?

Пример кода http://jsfiddle.net/unma777w/3/

```css
.days_table {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 285px;
}
.tbody_table {
  display: table-row-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-color: inherit;
}
.day,
.no_day {
  background: #ECE9E3;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
.day_curr {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF
}
.day_sun,
.no_day_sun,
.day_sun_right,
.no_day_sun_right {
  background: #E5E0DB;
}
.days,
.days_sun,
.day,
.no_day,
.day_curr,
.day_sun,
.no_day_sun {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  height: 25px;
}
.day_sun_right,
.no_day_sun_right,
.days_sun_right {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 0;
}
.mouseover {
  background: #ECE9E3;
}
.mouseover_s {
  background: #E5E0DB;
}
.mouseover_c {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.mouseover,
.mouseover_c,
.mouseover_s {
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 6px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px -2px 6px #000000;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="days_table">
  <tbody class="tbody_table">
    <tr class="row">
      <td align="center" class="days">ПН</td>
      <td align="center" class="days">ВТ</td>
      <td align="center" class="days">СР</td>
      <td align="center" class="days">ЧТ</td>
      <td align="center" class="days">ПТ</td>
      <td align="center" class="days_sun">СБ</td>
      <td align="center" class="days_sun_right">ВС</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day_sun">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day_sun_right" align="center">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="no_day" align="center">2</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">3</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">4</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">5</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">6</td>
      <td class="day_sun" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s &quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun&quot;">7</td>
      <td class="day_sun_right" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun_right&quot;">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">9</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">10</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">11</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">12</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">13</td>
      <td class="day_sun" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s &quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun&quot;">14</td>
      <td class="day_sun_right" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun_right&quot;">15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">16</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">17</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">18</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">19</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">20</td>
      <td class="day_sun" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s &quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun&quot;">21</td>
      <td class="day_sun_right" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun_right&quot;">22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">23</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">24</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">25</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">26</td>
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">27</td>
      <td class="day_sun" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s &quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun&quot;">28</td>
      <td class="day_sun_right" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover_s&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day_sun_right&quot;">29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="day" align="center" onmouseover="this.className=&quot;mouseover&quot;" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;day&quot;">30</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day_sun">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="no_day_sun_right">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ну и сам стиль для теней (полный вариант кода и стилей по ссылке выше)

```
box-shadow: 2px -2px 6px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px -2px 6px #000000;
```

Comment: добавь в вопрос html-код, таблицы стилей и картинки с ожидаемым и получаемым. и текст через спелл-чекер прогони, а то стыдно жы

Comment: Добавил ссылку на пример кода(html, css) на jsfiddle, опять же отображение в мозилле и хроме отличаються. Неужели никто не сталкивался с подобной ситуацией?

Comment: вопрос на переоткрытии

Comment: По ссылке нет ни одного box-shadow

Comment: Не совсем понял Вас, по ссылке есть пример, который у меня вызвал затруднение, и в нем, в части css, есть код описывающий box-shadow: `.mouseover,.mouseover_c,.mouseover_s{
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 6px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px -2px 6px #000000;
}`